# URL hit the wrong controller LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

In route.php I defined a route to a controller with 2 tokens on it.

```
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', 'projectController@detail');
```

Everything is working fine till when there is a call to a URL that have the same structure but has nothing to do with the one that has to be caught by that route shown below.

So when I have for example `"/admin/tags"`, the controller below is triggered because it has the same structure of `"/{category}/{slug}"` and of course it gives me an error, because it doesn't find a variable.

So now I fixed the problem moving that route on the bottom, but I believe I have to do something to prevent this behavior in advance, cause if I have multiple routes with different tokens everything would be triggered every time and there would be a mess.

So, what is it supposed to do in these cases?

P.S. I'm super beginner with Laravel

Comment: If you have a route like that (like a wildcard route), it's best to always put that at the bottom of the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use some constraint to the route, reference [parameters-regular-expression-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints). For example:

```
Route::get('user/{name}', function ($name) {
    //
})
->where('name', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

Or you can make the most specific before unspecific one. For example, in this sequence:

```
Route::get("/admin/tags", '......');
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', 'projectController@detail');
```

Answer (score 1):

if route need two token like that, i'm usually add prefix so my routes looks like this

```
Route::get('/categories/{category}/slug/{slug}', 'ProjectController@detail');
```

or

```
Route::get('/categories/{category}/{slug}', 'ProjectController@detail');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
I have constraints on every path parameter (as you always should) and unfortunately the conflict occurs between the following:

```
Route::get('{userId}/{path}', [
    'as' => 'products',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@click'
])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'path' => '[0-9a-fA-F]+']);

Route::get('link/{link_path}', [
    'as' => 'product-link',
    'uses' => 'UserController@productLink'
])->where(['link_path' => '[0-9a-fA-F]+']);
```

Where even though the one path has the prepended 'link/' in the path it still tried to hit the other.  By placing the route with the prepended 'link/' above the other route it took priority and works.

Personally I think if you have a condition that isn't met on the route where clause it should skip the route and move on to the next.  It doesn't really make sense to me to put a conditional that doesn't actually get passed up if the conditions aren't met.

Hopefully this helps anyone else having this issue.